# Spring Boot, Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am making a website in which I am trying to order ingredients. I choose and ingredient and enter its quantity, then I click add. I repeat it few times. Then I go to the next page, in which I chose a supplier. Then I press "Order".

It is expected to insert Nabavka into the database and open a page saying that the order was successful, but instead I get an Exception telling me that I can't initialize it lazily.

From NabavkaController.java:

```
@Autowired
NamirnicaRepository namr;
@Autowired
NabavkaRepository nabr;
@Autowired
DobavljacRepository dr;
@Autowired
NabavkaKorpaRepository nkr;...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@PostMapping(value = "sacuvajNabavku")
public String sacuvajNabavku(Dobavljac dobavljac, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<Namirnica> izabrane = (ArrayList<Namirnica>) request.getSession()
            .getAttribute("izabrane");
    List<Integer> brojevi = (ArrayList<Integer>) request.getSession()
            .getAttribute("brojevi");
    Nabavka n = new Nabavka();
    for (int i = 0; i < izabrane.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(izabrane.get(i).getNaziv());
        NabavkaKorpaPK nkPK = new NabavkaKorpaPK();
        nkPK.setIdNabavka(n.getIdNabavka());
        nkPK.setIdNamirnica(izabrane.get(i).getIdNamirnica());

        NabavkaKorpa nk = new NabavkaKorpa();
        nk.setId(nkPK);
        nk.setKolicina(brojevi.get(i));
        nk.setUkupnaCena(izabrane.get(i).getCenaNamirnice() * brojevi.get(0));
        izabrane.get(i).addNabavkaKorpa(nk);

        n.addNabavkaKorpa(nk);
        nabr.updateNamirnica(izabrane.get(i));
    }
    n.setDatumNabavke(new Date());
    n.setUkupnaCena(n.getNabavkaKorpas().stream().map(k -> k.getUkupnaCena()).reduce(0.0,
            (a, b) -> a + b));
    n.setDobavljac(dobavljac);
    dobavljac.addNabavka(n);
    nabr.save(n);
    return "uspehNabavka";
}
```

Nabavka.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Nabavka.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM Nabavka n")
public class Nabavka implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idNabavka;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date datumNabavke;

    private double ukupnaCena;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Dobavljac
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idDobavljac")
    private Dobavljac dobavljac;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Menadzer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idMenadzer", referencedColumnName="idMenadzer"),
        @JoinColumn(name="idRadnik", referencedColumnName="idRadnik")
        })
    private Menadzer menadzer;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idUser")
    private User user;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to NabavkaKorpa
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="nabavka", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<NabavkaKorpa> nabavkaKorpas = new ArrayList<NabavkaKorpa>();

    public Nabavka() {
    }

    public int getIdNabavka() {
        return this.idNabavka;
    }

    public void setIdNabavka(int idNabavka) {
        this.idNabavka = idNabavka;
    }

    public Date getDatumNabavke() {
        return this.datumNabavke;
    }

    public void setDatumNabavke(Date datumNabavke) {
        this.datumNabavke = datumNabavke;
    }

    public double getUkupnaCena() {
        return this.ukupnaCena;
    }

    public void setUkupnaCena(double ukupnaCena) {
        this.ukupnaCena = ukupnaCena;
    }

    public Dobavljac getDobavljac() {
        return this.dobavljac;
    }

    public void setDobavljac(Dobavljac dobavljac) {
        this.dobavljac = dobavljac;
    }

    public Menadzer getMenadzer() {
        return this.menadzer;
    }

    public void setMenadzer(Menadzer menadzer) {
        this.menadzer = menadzer;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<NabavkaKorpa> getNabavkaKorpas() {
        return this.nabavkaKorpas;
    }

    public void setNabavkaKorpas(List<NabavkaKorpa> nabavkaKorpas) {
        this.nabavkaKorpas = nabavkaKorpas;
    }

    public NabavkaKorpa addNabavkaKorpa(NabavkaKorpa nabavkaKorpa) {
        getNabavkaKorpas().add(nabavkaKorpa);
        nabavkaKorpa.setNabavka(this);

        return nabavkaKorpa;
    }

    public NabavkaKorpa removeNabavkaKorpa(NabavkaKorpa nabavkaKorpa) {
        getNabavkaKorpas().remove(nabavkaKorpa);
        nabavkaKorpa.setNabavka(null);

        return nabavkaKorpa;
    }

}
```

Namirnica.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Namirnica.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM Namirnica n")
public class Namirnica implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idNamirnica;

    private double cenaNamirnice;

    private String kolicina;

    private String naziv;
    
    private int stanje;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to NabavkaKorpa
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="namirnica")
    private List<NabavkaKorpa> nabavkaKorpas = new ArrayList<NabavkaKorpa>();

    public Namirnica() {
    }

    public int getIdNamirnica() {
        return this.idNamirnica;
    }

    public void setIdNamirnica(int idNamirnica) {
        this.idNamirnica = idNamirnica;
    }

    public double getCenaNamirnice() {
        return this.cenaNamirnice;
    }

    public void setCenaNamirnice(double cenaNamirnice) {
        this.cenaNamirnice = cenaNamirnice;
    }

    public String getKolicina() {
        return this.kolicina;
    }

    public void setKolicina(String kolicina) {
        this.kolicina = kolicina;
    }

    public String getNaziv() {
        return this.naziv;
    }

    public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
        this.naziv = naziv;
    }
    
    public int getStanje() {
        return this.stanje;
    }

    public void setStanje(int stanje) {
        this.stanje = stanje;
    }

    public List<NabavkaKorpa> getNabavkaKorpas() {
        return this.nabavkaKorpas;
    }

    public void setNabavkaKorpas(List<NabavkaKorpa> nabavkaKorpas) {
        this.nabavkaKorpas = nabavkaKorpas;
    }

    public NabavkaKorpa addNabavkaKorpa(NabavkaKorpa nabavkaKorpa) {
        getNabavkaKorpas().add(nabavkaKorpa);
        nabavkaKorpa.setNamirnica(this);

        return nabavkaKorpa;
    }

    public NabavkaKorpa removeNabavkaKorpa(NabavkaKorpa nabavkaKorpa) {
        getNabavkaKorpas().remove(nabavkaKorpa);
        nabavkaKorpa.setNamirnica(null);

        return nabavkaKorpa;
    }

}
```

NabavkaKorpa.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="NabavkaKorpa.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM NabavkaKorpa n")
public class NabavkaKorpa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private NabavkaKorpaPK id;

    private int kolicina;

    private double ukupnaCena;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Nabavka
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="idNabavka", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Nabavka nabavka;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Namirnica
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="idNamirnica", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Namirnica namirnica;

    public NabavkaKorpa() {
    }

    public NabavkaKorpaPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(NabavkaKorpaPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getKolicina() {
        return this.kolicina;
    }

    public void setKolicina(int kolicina) {
        this.kolicina = kolicina;
    }

    public double getUkupnaCena() {
        return this.ukupnaCena;
    }

    public void setUkupnaCena(double ukupnaCena) {
        this.ukupnaCena = ukupnaCena;
    }

    public Nabavka getNabavka() {
        return this.nabavka;
    }

    public void setNabavka(Nabavka nabavka) {
        this.nabavka = nabavka;
    }

    public Namirnica getNamirnica() {
        return this.namirnica;
    }

    public void setNamirnica(Namirnica namirnica) {
        this.namirnica = namirnica;
    }

}
```

NabavkaKorpaPK.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class NabavkaKorpaPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idNamirnica;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idNabavka;

    public NabavkaKorpaPK() {
    }
    public int getIdNamirnica() {
        return this.idNamirnica;
    }
    public void setIdNamirnica(int idNamirnica) {
        this.idNamirnica = idNamirnica;
    }
    public int getIdNabavka() {
        return this.idNabavka;
    }
    public void setIdNabavka(int idNabavka) {
        this.idNabavka = idNabavka;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof NabavkaKorpaPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        NabavkaKorpaPK castOther = (NabavkaKorpaPK)other;
        return 
            (this.idNamirnica == castOther.idNamirnica)
            && (this.idNabavka == castOther.idNabavka);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.idNamirnica;
        hash = hash * prime + this.idNabavka;
        
        return hash;
    }
}
```

NabavkaKorpaRepository.java:

```
public interface NabavkaKorpaRepository extends JpaRepository<NabavkaKorpa, NabavkaKorpaPK> {

}
```

NabavkaRepository.java:

```
public interface NabavkaRepository extends JpaRepository<Nabavka, Integer>, NabavkaRepoSpecific {

}
```

NabavkaRepoSpeicific.java

```
public interface NabavkaRepoSpecific {

    public void updateNamirnica(Namirnica namirnica);

}
```

NabavkaRepoSpecificImpl.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class NabavkaRepoSpecificImpl implements NabavkaRepoSpecific {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void updateNamirnica(Namirnica namirnica) {
        try {
            em.merge(namirnica);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

NamirnicaRepository.java:

```
public interface NamirnicaRepository extends JpaRepository<Namirnica, Integer> {

}
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Namirnica.nabavkaKorpas, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:614) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at model.Namirnica.addNabavkaKorpa(Namirnica.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.NabavkaController.sacuvajNabavku(NabavkaController.java:95) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

EDIT: I get Namirnicas from a session. Here's the GitHub [link](https://github.com/IgorArnaut/MIS-Picerija).

Comment: You have no `@Transactional` it seems. Your call `izabrane.get(i).addNabavkaKorpa(nk);` causes this error, because you did load the data at some point, but didn't initialize the dependencies properly. Also, consider naming your entities/variables in English, especially when asking a question here. It makes it much easier for us to understand your code

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think `@Transactional` will not help. See my answer for the details please.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of an error that you get a list `List<Namirnica> izabrane` at one step (lets name it `A`) of the flow, but work with `Namirinica` items at the second step(`B`).

This list is lazy by default. It means that you can access it at `A` point only (when `@Transaction`/Persistent Context/Hibernate Session is open).

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="namirnica")
private List<NabavkaKorpa> nabavkaKorpas = new ArrayList<NabavkaKorpa>();
```

Even opening a new transaction at the `B` point will not help, because it will be another Persistent context/Hibernate session (not the same as in the `A` point).

You can try to make `nabavkaKorpas` `EAGER`, probably it will help.
But you have a design problem.

**Common rule**

Never work with an associated collection from the `@OneToMany` part.

**How to fix**

You have to save a new `NabavkaKorpa`, not `Namirnica`.

```java
NabavkaKorpa nabavka = new NabavkaKorpa();
nabavka.setNamirnica(namirnica);

nabavkaKorpaRepositiry.save(nabavka);
```

You don't even need `Namirnica` to do it.

For Hibernate

```java
Namirnica namirnica= new Namirnica();
namirnica.setId(namirnicaId);

NabavkaKorpa nabavka = new NabavkaKorpa();
nabavka.setNamirnica(namirnica);

nabavkaKorpaRepositiry.save(nabavka);
```

For Spring Data (to not having additional query to get Namirnica from a database)

```java
Namirnica namirnica= namirinicaRepositiry.getOne(namirnicaId);

NabavkaKorpa nabavka = new NabavkaKorpa();
nabavka.setNamirnica(namirnica);

nabavkaKorpaRepositiry.save(nabavka);
```

**Notes about Persistent Context**

When you use `@Transactional` annotation on the method, there is not only an open transaction inside that method, but also opened Persistent Context/Hibernate Session. So such `@Transactional` approach that using widely in Spring is a bit confused.

When Persistent Context is open, Hibernate observe all changes that are made for persistent objects, like `Namirnica` and `NabavkaKorpa`, and try to save them to the database, so you even don't need to call `save()` method of a repository (but I prefer to explicitly call it).
So in such situation you, probably, can keep association in the valid state from two sides: `Namirnica` has `NabavkaKorpa` in the list and `NabavkaKorpa` refers to `Namirnica`. But usually I don't keep such things.

When Persistent Context is closed, Hibernate doesn't observe changes and you don't have to keep associations in the valid state. When you call a repository method, for each such call a separate Persistent Context is created. And all such calls are independent from the Hibernate point of view. You can enable SQL logging and see what happens.

So you don't need to do

```java
izabrane.get(i).addNabavkaKorpa(nk);
```

Just work with `NabavkaKorpa`.

**Notes**

It is a very bad idea having `CascadeType.ALL` here.

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="idNamirnica", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Namirnica namirnica;
```

Comment: I retained: `NabavkaKorpa nk = new NabavkaKorpa();
nk.setNamirnica(izabrane.get(i));
nk.setKolicina(brojevi.get(i));
nk.setUkupnaCena(izabrane.get(i).getCenaNamirnice() * brojevi.get(0));
izabrane.get(i).addNabavkaKorpa(nk);
nkr.save(nk);`. That didn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: @IgorArnaut Hello Igor. I have added `Notes about Persistent Context` section special for you.

Comment: I did everything what you've said, but now I get org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class model.NabavkaKorpa.

Comment: @IgorArnaut You have to set `NabavkaKorpaPK` of course. Also, using composite keys is almost always a bad  idea. It is very inconvenient to work with them.

Comment: @IgorArnaut And, please, keep in mind that I don't provide full solution, just show a direction to move.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone: I had added `@Transactional` on my method, but it still did not work. In my case, the reason seemed to be that the lazy get which triggered the exception was inside a `Single.map`, so the `@Transactional` could not reach inside.

I removed the `@Transactional` annotation, and wrapped the lazy get inside a `transactionTemplate.execute`, like so:

```java
private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
...
private void myNonTransactionalMethod() {
  mySingle.map(result -> {
    transactionTemplate.execute(() -> {
      myEntity.getLazyListOfEntities()...
    });
  });
}
```